# [R]:RDCOMClient and outlook : how to send to multiple recipients or cc someone?

Tags: r, outlook

as title, I have tried and failed... This is a piece of code I found in another thread and it works for only one recipient. Thanks in Advance.

```
OutApp <- COMCreate("Outlook.Application")
outMail = OutApp$CreateItem(0)
outMail[["To"]] = "xxx@xxx"
outMail[["subject"]] = "xx"
outMail[["body"]] = ""
outMail$Send()
```

Comment: I know that I can run this same code x times for x recipients and send x emails, but I am trying to look for a way to send one email only...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the To/CC/BCC properties to a ";" separated list of emails or call `MailItem.Recipients.Add` for each recipient.

Comment: thanks, it worked... forgot it should be ";" as in outlook...outMail[["To"]] = paste ("aaa@aaa.com", "bbb@bbb.com", sep = ";", collapse = NULL)

Answer (score 4):

use this highlighted code to share the emails to multiple lists

```
outMail[["To"]] = paste("xxxx@xxx.com","another@xxx.com", sep=";", collapse=NULL)
```

same logic with Cc for multiple list except below thing

```
outMail[["Cc"]]= "xxx@xxx.com"
```